# Start and stop button in maui

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, maui

I'm doing a ping app using .net maui

the code is working very well, however, i got a problem with the button when i tried to do two events in the same button which is start and stop

the mainpage.xaml have this code using listview

```
<Entry  x:Name="IPEntry"
                    Text="{Binding ip}"
                    Placeholder="IP Address"                    
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100"
                    />
 <Button
                x:Name="start"
                Text="start"
                Command="{Binding StartCmmand}"            
                    
                HorizontalOptions="Center"               
                Clicked="start_Clicked"
                    
                />
<ListView
                x:Name="listViewRes"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                HeightRequest="400"
                WidthRequest="400"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                ItemsSource="{Binding pingcollection}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Status_ip}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding IPAddress}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding TTL}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ResponseTime}"/>
                                
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

the mainpage.xaml.cs as following

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{ 
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModels.PingViewModel();       
    }
    int i = 0;
    
    private async void start_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        PingViewModel pp = new PingViewModel();
        
    }

   
}
```

while the function of the ping is in PingViewModel class

```
public class PingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _IP;
        private string _Status;
        private string _TTL;
        private string _ResponseTime;
        public string _Send;
        public bool flag = true;

            public PingViewModel()
        {
            pingcollection = new ObservableCollection<PingData>();
            if (flag==true)
            { 
                StartCmmand = new Command(Startc);
            }
            else
            {
                StartCmmand = new Command(Stopc);
            }
            //  StopCmmand = new Command(Stopc);
        }
        
        public async void Startc()
        {
            var ping_data = new PingData();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions
            {
                Ttl = 200
            };
          
            while (flag == true)
            
            {
                
                using (Ping ping = new Ping())
                {
                    PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip.ToString());
                   // PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip.ToString());
                    if (string.Equals(reply.Status.ToString(), "Success"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ping_data.TTL = reply.Options.Ttl.ToString();
                            ping_data.Status_ip = reply.Status.ToString();
                            ping_data.IPAddress = reply.Address.ToString();
                            ping_data.ResponseTime = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();
                            Send = reply.Options.Ttl.ToString();
                        }
                        catch (PingException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {                       
                        ping_data.Status_ip = reply.Status.ToString();                   
                    }
                }
               // Stopc();
                
                //flag = false;
                pingcollection.Insert(0, ping_data);
                
                    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                    OnPropertyChanged();
             }
                //pingcollection.Clear();
                //OnPropertyChanged();
            //true = stop , flase = start
            
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
```

while the data is passed using pingdata.cs

```
public class PingData
   {
       public string IPAddress { get; set; }
       public string Status_ip { get; set; }
       public string TTL { get; set; }
       public string ResponseTime { get; set; }
       public int Count { get; set; }
   }
```

could you help me please?

i tried many ways to do the start and stop button but it didn't work

Comment: you have not told us what specific problem you are having, just "I got a problem".  There is no `Button` element in the XAML you posted.  Please read [ask] before posting for guidance on what information should be included in a question

Comment: the problem is  the app is working in the beginning but once I press the button again to stop, it keeps hanging and won't stop the ping

Comment: it is my fault, i didn't add the button in xaml code

Comment: first, you have both a `Clicked` and a `Command` defined for the button.  Pick one or the other, not both.  Second, you have not posted the code for either the clicked event or the command, so we have no idea what they are doing.

Comment: from reading the code you did post, it seems like just setting `flag = false;` would be enough to stop the current ping

Comment: i added all the code now
i tried to use the flag to just do start and stop again, but still doesn't work

Comment: every time you click Start you are creating a **new instance** of `PingViewModel`.  You need to use the existing instance that you create when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

every time you execute `start_Clicked` you are creating a **new instance** of the VM

```
private async void start_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    PingViewModel pp = new PingViewModel();
```

instead, delete that line and just use the reference you already have in the constructor

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = PingViewModel = new ViewModels.PingViewModel();       
}
```